# Time to first fix

Tags: android, gps

Is the time to first fix the same as long as I don't shutdown and restart the gps engine? No matter when I check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about different devices and hardware.  If you are reliant on time to fix, then your app will only ever work with the same model of the same device, and probably with the same kernel mods.

Now consider this scenario.

I start the fix.  I'm outside on the street with a clear view of the sky.  I get a fix in xxx seconds.  Now I move inside my house.  I don't change anything, only my location.  Then I start another fix.  Will it take xxx seconds?

I suspect that you have asked the wrong question.  Why is the time to fix important to you?

I don't know the direct answer to your question as asked, and I doubt that there is an empirical answer.  The best direct answer I can give you is "it's indeterminate".

Comment: I'm just running benchmarking tests on the device's gps. So I wanted to know how reliable the time to first fix was.